# Select monitor for indicator information

Tags: unity, 13.04, multiple-monitors, indicator

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 on a computer with two monitors. The indicators are visible in the upper right corner of both monitors, but if an indicator has notifications to show (such as the arrival of mail), that information is only displayed on the right-hand monitor.

Can I change that so the information is displayed on the left monitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found a way to set a specific monitor (left vs. right) but you can have the notification appear in whichever screen has focus (following the mouse).

You can use dconf editor and go to `apps > notify-osd` and change `multihead-mode` to `focus-follow`

or from the terminal: 
`gsettings set com.canonical.notify-osd multihead-mode focus-follow`

You can test this with `notify-send test`

Comment: That's perfect, Argusvision. Thank you! (I will award bounty soon -  I'm not allowed to do it yet.)